# Accessing JavaScript variables from Objective-C in XCode

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, variables, cordova

Recently I've tried creating an app for iOS using HTML5 and JS and building it with cordova.

Then I thought I want more functions that are already in iOS sdk. So I opened the cordova project in XCode and frankly don't know:

How should I access JavaScript variables with my Objective-C functions or vice-versa?

Is it even possible? I know that JS has no specific type for variables, whereas C has.

Comment: did u try looking at the JavaScriptCore.Framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a Cordova app and access iOS functions, you use plugins:
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/

If you want to use Javascript from an iOS program, you don't use Cordova. Then you use the "JavaScriptCore" library in XCode: 
http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/javascriptcore-and-ios-7/

Good luck on both.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute JS from your iOS code you have to use following pattern

```
NSString* jsCall = @"1 + 1;"
NSString* res = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall];
```

where `webView` is the property of the CDVViewController which is the base class for the `MainController` created for you by Cordova.

To be able to call iOS code from the JavaScript you have to use Cordova plugins. Explanation how to create Cordova plugins could be found in the [Plugin Development Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) section of the official Corodova docs